# Disable middle mouse button on title bar "alt tab"-like behaviour

Tags: mouse, linux-mint

I am using Linux Mint 17 and whenever i push the middle mouse button on a title bar i experience an "alt-tab"-like behavior where the window i am currently using goes in the background. This is quite annoying in Chrome since i usually use the middle mouse button to close tabs. Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just searched in Google for: Linux Mint 17 disable middle mouse button titlebar click and found the following with needed info: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=177694&p=921285

Basically from third post on that page:

> Is this with LM 17 Cinnamon? If so, Settings -> Windows -> Action on
>   Title Bar Middle-Click

Comment: yup yup, anytime.  Glad I could help :-)